# Get Dialog Box as the App Starts VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to get a dialog box with two buttons as soon as the program is executed in VB.net.
Thanks!

PS - Help a novice programmer!

Answer (score 0):

You can create yourself a new form with the buttons or controls you wanted. Then you could set this form as the startup form. You could do this by visiting the `Project` menu --> `Project Properties` --> `Application` tab --> `Startup object`. From the dropdown, select the form you created.

Then that form will be shown at first everytime you start your application.

Otherwise, you could use call the newly created form within your existing form's `Load` event, by calling the `show()` method of the new form.